# OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException was unhandled + C# + Another Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium, currently exploring on how it works. Started using it for ASP.NET application, i am using C# Selenium driver, IE Driver server ( 32 bit as it's faster than 64 bit)

I navigated to a application there I am clicking a link which should take me to ANOTHER WEBSITE where I have to find a textbox and clear it and enter some text (SendKeys) and then click a button.

When it goes to a another website from main website, It's unable to find the element ( I tried using by.ID and by.Name). I made sure element is available on the webpage. As recommened I used ImplicitlyWait but no luck, tried thread.sleep() no lucK.. Does the test needs to be on the same website which launched initially ?.. Below is my code snippet.. Please help me..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.Threading;

namespace mySelenium
{
    class Program
    {
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\Users\msbyuva\Downloads\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.45.0\");
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://MyorgName.org/Apps/Sites/2015/login.aspx");

        IWebElement userNameTxtBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_UserName"));
        userNameTxtBox.SendKeys("MSBYUVA");

        IWebElement passwordTxtBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_Password"));
        passwordTxtBox.SendKeys("1234");

        var myButton = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_LoginButton"));
        myButton.Click();

        var EMailLink = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Email Testing Link"));
        EMailLink .Click();

        //Thread.Sleep(10000);

// -- HERE IT IS THROWING ERROR (ANOTHER WEBSITE AFTER CLICKING HYPERLINK)

    var toEmailAddress  = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtTo"));
                toEmailAddress.Clear();
                toEmailAddress.SendKeys("msbyuva@gmail.com");


            var chkEmailAttachment = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ChkAttachMent"));
            chkEmailAttachment.Click();

            var sendEmailButton = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BtnSend"));
            sendEmailButton.Click();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to switchTo newly opened window and set focus to it in order to send any commands to it

```
string currentHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.ToList().Last());
```

After you done with newly opened window do(as need)

```
driver.Close();
driver.SwitchTo().Window(currentHandle );
```

More perfectly use [PopupWindowFinder](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/AllMembers_T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_PopupWindowFinder.htm) class

```
string currentHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
PopupWindowFinder popUpWindow = new PopupWindowFinder(driver);
string popupWindowHandle = popUpWindow.Click(EMailLink );
driver.SwitchTo().Window(popupWindowHandle);

//then do the email stuff

 var toEmailAddress  = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtTo"));
                toEmailAddress.Clear();
                toEmailAddress.SendKeys("msbyuva@gmail.com");


            var chkEmailAttachment = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ChkAttachMent"));
            chkEmailAttachment.Click();

            var sendEmailButton = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BtnSend"));
            sendEmailButton.Click();
        }
    }
}

//closing pop up window
driver.Close();
driver.SwitchToWindow(currentHandle);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response.. It works but currently in the application when clicked on EMailLink, another window open in a new window (as taregt = _blank) but this is openign as separate window. Also after executing driver.Close();
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(popupWindowHandle);   New window is closed but it's raising ERROR  at "driver.SwitchTo().Window(popupWindowHandle);"   "NoSuchWindowException was unhandled"    No window found..

Comment: Are you saying two windows open after the click?

Comment: No after the click  new window is opened as popup -- as per the application when clicked it opens in another tab but not as new window.... coming to the error... It's working fine.. it's mistake form my end..

Comment: Yeah may be I am new to this stuff don't know really.. but  your post helped me... thanks..!!

Comment: Well, this window handles is little confusing. Are you facing any other issue? I will try to help if so